# Simple PHP upload to Google Compute Engine VM (instance) don't work

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, upload

I am new in Google Cloud and I've read the article  "Upload File To Google Cloud Storage Using PHP". I need to do something that looks more simple than that but I had some troubles with google and I would be very grateful if you could help me

I have a simple HTTP form with select a JPG image and post it via HTTP FORM to a PHP with receives the file via `$_FILE` and saves it into a folder named /files into the disk.  The thing is that this simple script works fine in the older web host server ( Apache/PHP) and now that I moved all the files to an instance in a VM in  Google Compute Engine it doesn´t work.

I printed `basename($_FILES["file"]["name"])` or `basename($_FILES["file"]["size"])` and it seems that the file came empty.

What do you think I am doing wrong?

```
<form id="docform" name="docform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php"> 
    <input type="file" name="Filedata" id="Filedata">
    <input name="FLD" type="hidden" id="FLD" value="files" />
    <input name="NOM" type="hidden" id="NOM" value="001111111" />
</form>
```

```
$FLD=$_GET["FLD"];          //folder to save file
$NOM=$_GET["NOM"];          //suggested file name ... ex :: 004545

$MSG=""; $CHK=""; $FILD="Filedata"; 

if($_FILES[$FILD]['size']==0 && $_FILES[$FILD]['error']==0){    
    $CHK="si"; $MSG="File loaded empty.";
}else if($_FILES[$FILD]["error"] != 0){ 
    $CHK="si"; $MSG="problems reading file";
}

if($CHK!="si"){

    $NAM=basename($_FILES[$FILD]["name"]);                  // actual filename
    $TMP=basename($_FILES[$FILD]["tmp_name"]);              // temp name 
    $EXT=strtolower(pathinfo($NAM,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));     // extension

    $DIR=strtolower(pathinfo($NAM,PATHINFO_DIRNAME));       // dir info
    $BAS=strtolower(pathinfo($NAM,PATHINFO_BASENAME));      // basename info
    $SIZ=basename($_FILES[$FILD]["size"]);                  // size info

    // writing file
    $FIL=$NOM.".".$EXT;
    $FILE=$FLD."/".$FIL;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$FILD]['tmp_name'], $FILE);

    }
```

Regards

Comment: Include your code in your question. Read these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: oh you're right

Comment: Show the HTML form in your question.

Comment: did it ... i think the problem is in google cloud ... i have tried with another 2 servers and it worked fine ... the form uses POST but is received as GET in VM Google Cloud Engine.

Comment: This parameter is wrong `$FILD="file"`. It should be `$FILD="Filedata"`

Comment: sorry my mistake .. yes it's Filedata .. but it still doesn't work.  I had tested the size of the post with $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']; and it shows a number of bytes according the selected file but i can't get any element of the POST and display it. All of them appears as null